# What's wrong with my bitmasking?

Tags: c++, arrays, bitmask

1. I should create n arrays of bits, n is not a constant! Why program gives garbage instead of my arrays?
2. How to write obtained arrays to a file, so that they were there in a bit?

Example:

```
class bits {
     int *m;
     int razm;
     int num;
     int N;
  public:
     bits(int r,int NN) { N=NN; razm=r; num=0; m=new int[N*razm]; }
     ~bits() {delete(m);}
     void add() { m[num/32]|=(1>>(num%32)); num++;}
     bool read(int n,int bit) 
            { 
          return m[(razm*n-bit)/32]&(1>>((razm*n-bit)%32)); }
            };

    void main()
    {
    bits x(8,10000);
    char ch[100]={"11111122223334445698"};
     for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
      {
      for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
    if(ch[i]&(1<<j))
            x.add();
      }

     for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
      {
      for(int j=0;j<8;j++) { if(x.read(i,j)) cout << "1"; else cout << "0"; }
      cout << "\n";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Removing [c] tag; C doesn't have classes and C and C++ are not the same language; please don't use both tags.

Comment: have you researched on the topic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help in writing program in c++. Arrays of bits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884729/need-help-in-writing-program-in-c-arrays-of-bits)

Answer (score 1):

You are shifting right

```
(1>>(num%32))
(1>>((razm*n-bit)%32))
```

where you should shift left. Shifting to the right produces a 0 except for when the remainder is 0.

Comment: To shift left, write `1 << (num%32)` for example.

Comment: ok, great thanks! And what about second question? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Well, I don't understand what you want there, do you want to write the bit-pattern to the file, or a textual representation?

Comment: One question per question please - please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: That does not matter, at least in the file without an extension, the main thing that kept the structure of the array

Answer (score 0):

Your `new int[N*razm]` expression doesn't initialize the memory so your bit array starts with indeterminate contents (possibly random garbage). If you want to value initialized the array to zeros change it to `new int[N*razm]()`, note the trailing parentheses.